# Failed to load please make sure its declared

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, webview, admob

I am trying to load interstitial ads in my application but its not loading. I have declared all things in my app but logcat says another story.

Here is the logcat

```
W/Ads     (24737):  Could not find com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity, please make sure it is declared in AndroidManifest.xml

 I/iu.UploadsManager(13004):  End new media; added: 0, uploading: 0, time: 134 ms
 I/iu.UploadsManager(13004):  End new media; added: 0, uploading: 0, time: 69 ms
 I/dex2oat (25072):  dex2oat took 20.680s (threads: 2)
 I/dex2oat (25184):  /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-     arg  --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=div --runtime-arg -  Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --dex- file=/data/data/com.tech.slidechat/cache/ads-489919204.jar --oat-fd=31 --oat-location=/data/data/com.tech.slidechat/cache/ads-489919204.dex --runtime-arg - Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m
I/dex2oat (25184):  dex2oat took 78.925ms (threads: 2)
I/Ads     (25163):  CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter  created.
I/Ads     (25163):  Starting ad request.
I/Ads     (25163):  Use  AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3DA69D7DC8C309681C9A4C6D3386B798") to get test ads on this device.
I/Ads     (13004):  CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
I/Ads     (13004):  CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Creating Application Cache with manifest https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.appcache", source:   https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Checking event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Downloading event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (0 of 1) https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.js", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Progress event (1 of 1) ", source:    https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
 I/chromium(13004):  [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Application Cache Cached event", source: https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html (0)
I/Ads     (25163):  Ad finished loading.
W/Ads     (25163):  It is not recommended to show an interstitial before  onAdLoaded completes.
 I/ActivityManager(669):  START u0 {cmp=com.tech.slidechat/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity (has extras)} from uid 10072 on display 0
I/ActivityManager(669):  Start proc com.tech.slidechat for activity com.tech.slidechat/com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity: pid=25337 uid=10072 gids={50072, 9997, 3003, 1028, 1015} abi=armeabi-v7a
 W/Ads     (25337):  Could not get info for ad overlay.
```

Here is my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tech.example" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/google"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:process=":remote"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
```

My main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  SlidingTabLayout tabs;
  ViewPager viewPager;
  TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
  Toolbar toolbar;
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;


CharSequence Titles[]={ "tab1", "tab2", "tab3" };
int Numboftabs =3;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("AALUBHALU")
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);



     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
      setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);



    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }

        @Override
        public int getDividerColor(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    // Prepare an Interstitial Ad Listener
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }
    });
}
public void displayInterstitial() {
    // If Ads are loaded, show Interstitial else show nothing.
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}



}
```

ProGuard rules

```
For Google Play Services
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
 public *; 
} 

For old ads classes
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
 public *;
 }

For mediation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

Other required classes for Google Play Services
Read more at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class     

 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
 public static final *** NULL;
 }
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
 protected Object[][] getContents();
 }

 -keep public class   

com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
 @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
 }

 -keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final ** CREATOR;
 }
```

I don't know what is wrong please help me find out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

u should make the manifest like this:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
    android:process=":remote"/>
```

AdActivity must be in the same process with the main Activity

Comment: i found a better solution.
that is add "android:multiprocess="true" in AdActivity instead of "android:process"

Answer (score 0):

Start by calling `interstitial.show()` at a natural break point in your app instead of from `onAdLoaded()`, otherwise you will provide an extremeley poor user experience and most likely get your Admob account banned.

You also haven't included any log prior to the warning about AdActivityand you haven't included timestamps in the logcat so it is hard to tell exactly what is going on. But start by making sure that the AndroidManifest above has actually made it into your APK in one piece.

Comment: Yuh done that also but results are same now not getting any warnings regarding to manifest, only this error persists"Could not get info for ad overlay" is there is something needs to be done in layout? And i am using webview in fragments.

Comment: Are you using an interstitial adUnitId?

Comment: Yes of course.Now something interesting happening, the ad appear for just a moment giving the same error above in the logcat and closes itself. I can't see which ad is loading just a white screen appears and then close.

Comment: If it was accidentally configured (in Admob) as a banner adUnitId you could be getting issues like this.

Comment: No the issue is certainly not that, even the test ads are not displaying.

Comment: I double check it but i am using the correct id even i created a another one but the result is same.

Comment: One more important point is that i am not using mainactivity to call ads instead i am using one of my fragments which uses relativelayout.